# Changing highlight time when searching

Tags: emacs

When I perform search in emacs, the available matches are highlighted for around 1 second.

How can I change this?
Is there any customize-group for setting search highlight time options? (in isearch there is no such entry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the customize group is `lazy-highlight`

(which is one of the child groups listed at the bottom of the `isearch` group's buffer, incidentally.)

edit: Although it sounds like you're saying that the highlighting disappears again after a second with no intervention on your part, which would seem like a conflict with something else, as that's not the default behaviour. (You can run `emacs -Q` to test the defaults.)

Assuming that `lazy-highlight-cleanup` is being called unexpectedly, you could call `debug-on-entry` on that function to check the stack trace and see where that call is coming from. You'll have to <kbd>c</kbd>ontinue past some expected calls when initiating the search. Use `cancel-debug-on-entry` when you're done.

See also:

Standard debugger commands:
<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(elisp) Debugger Commands")` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Main manual entry for debugging elisp:
<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(elisp) Debugging")` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `lazy-highlight-interval` variable, for example:

```
(setq lazy-highlight-interval 0)
```